# Metadata API retrieve limit

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, package.xml

I'm implementing a metadata backup system for a salesforce org.
I have already implemented the retrieve process based on package.xml.
However due to the size of the org the command with a unique package.xml is not compatible with the limits of 10,000 files or 39 MB for the zip file.

Consequently, I have adjusted the process to work on package.xml blocks, but there are some metadata such as profiles and translations that depend on the other metadata required at the same time.
I could not find any online documentation indicating which metadata has this behavior and their respective dependencies.
Does anyone have this information?

Or can you tell me a way to work around the limit on the retrieve API so that I can use a unique package.xml?

Comment: Not exactly his remit, but Scott Wells, the developer for Illuminated Cloud (the fabulous Salesforce IDE that runs within IntelliJ IDEA), is likely to have faced and resolved this sort of problem himself. Perhaps you could post a query on the Illuminated Cloud Q&A forum?

Comment: Also, have you considered simply leveraging the sfdx CLI to pull all metadata?

Comment: layouts, lightning pages (flexipage) come to mind

Comment: Thaks Phil, I'll also try the Illuminated Cloud Q&A forum.
Regarding the sfdx CLI pull command, it only works on Scratch Orgs. Instead, I have to retrieve the meta from a production organization, so I have to use the retrieve command but it has the same limitations as the metadata API, that is, it requires a manifest or list the metadata I want to retrieve.